# efficiency working with dates in R

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a function that I use to calculate the difference between two dates. I have a dataset with over 400K records, and I am having difficulty with getting it to work at scale.

The function:

```
library(lubridate)
get_recency <- function(last_gift_date, refresh_date) {
  last_gift_date <- as.Date(last_gift_date)
  refresh_date <- as.Date(refresh_date)

  case_when(
    is.na(last_gift_date) ~ "ERROR",
    last_gift_date > refresh_date ~ "ERROR",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(12) >= refresh_date ~ "0-12",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(24) >= refresh_date ~ "13-24",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(36) >= refresh_date ~ "25-36",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(48) >= refresh_date ~ "37-48",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(60) >= refresh_date ~ "49-60",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(72) >= refresh_date ~ "61-72",
    last_gift_date %m+% months(84) >= refresh_date ~ "73-84",
    TRUE ~ "85+")
}
```

If I pass a single date into the `refresh_date` parameter it seems to execute fine, however when I pass an equivalent length vector in, it takes super long.

Any thoughts on how to improve this would be appreciated.

Example to run the code:

```
a<- c("2014-01-29", "2015-04-07", "2015-04-10")
b<- c(NA, "2014-01-29", "2015-04-07")
get_recency(b,a)

# OUTPUT
#[1] "ERROR" "13-24" "0-12"
```

**UPDATE *2017-07-10***
I took the advise of @Akrun and made use of the `cut()` function. It has the benefit of being quicker and more succinct code. Results below.

```
get_recency <- function(last_gift_date, refresh_date) {
  last_gift_date <- as.Date(last_gift_date)
  refresh_date <- as.Date(refresh_date)

  x <- (as.yearmon(refresh_date)-as.yearmon(last_gift_date))*12

  x <- replace(x, is.na(x), -Inf)

  cut(x, breaks = c(-Inf, -0.000001, 12, 24, 36, 48, 60, 72, 84, Inf), 
      labels = c("ERROR", "0-12", "13-24", "25-36", "37-48",
                 "49-60", "61-72", "73-84", "85+"),
      include.lowest = T)
}
```

Comment: I think you can do this with `cut` or `findInterval`

Comment: You could try: `library(mondate); v <- MonthsBetween(mondate(a), mondate(b)); x <- cut(v, c(0:7 * 12, Inf))`

Comment: Your solution doesn't account for days of the two dates?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

a <- c("2014-01-29", "2015-04-07", "2015-04-10", "2025-04-10")
b <- c(NA, "2014-01-29", "2015-04-07", "2015-04-07")
intervals <- 12 * 1:7

get_recency <- function(last_gift_date, refresh_date, intervals) {


  last_gift_date <- as.Date(last_gift_date)
  refresh_date <- as.Date(refresh_date)

  intervals_chr <- c(
    "ERROR",
    paste(c(0, intervals[-length(intervals)] + 1), intervals, sep = "-"), 
    paste0(tail(intervals, 1) + 1, "+")
  )

  code <- sapply(c(0, intervals), function(n) {
    last_gift_date %m+% months(n) < refresh_date
  }) %>%
    rowSums()

  if_else(condition = is.na(code), true = "ERROR", 
          false = intervals_chr[code + 1])
}

get_recency(b, a, intervals)

[1] "ERROR" "13-24" "0-12"  "85+"
```

Is this faster?

Comment: Not sure if it is faster, however it is certainly more complicated to understand.